# OverlayFS: Is mounting /foo/lower:/foo/upper to /foo safe?

Tags: overlayfs, union-mount

Consider the following union mount:

```
mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/.pre-foo/lower,upperdir=/.pre-foo/upper,workdir=/.pre-foo/work overlay /foo
```

I would like to obfuscate that `/.pre-foo` to minimize the chance of some process to modify my underlying folders while the union is mounted. I could get it with the following "recursive" mount:

```
mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/foo/lower,upperdir=/foo/upper,workdir=/foo/work overlay /foo
```

My question is: Is this safe? Is there any security and/or performance risk in mounting an overlay "recursively"?

Comment: yes. its fine. do it.

Comment: I believe the question might be more clearly stated as follows:  (1) Can `lowerdir`, `upperdir` and `workdir` be nested _inside_ the mount point (`/foo`, in this case)?  (2) Is such nesting secure and performant?  (3) After the mount is performed, will the nested `lowerdir`, `upperdir` and `workdir` be hidden, protected, and only accessible through the "view" provided by the overlay?